# Count Distinct Values in one column table related to another column table Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, star-schema

I want to visualize in a power bi chart the distinct count values from one column referencing another table column. This should be done using a measure, not a calculated column. So I have a fact table like this one:

| user_id | application_id | client_id | date_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 | 3 | 3 |

Here is the user dimension table:

| user_id | user_code | name | status | date_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Johann | 1 | 07-23-2021 |
| 2 | 1 | Johann | 0 | 07-30-2021 |
| 3 | 1 | Johann | 1 | 10-17-2021 |
| 4 | 2 | Ana | 0 | 12-14-2021 |
| 5 | 2 | Ana | 1 | 01-22-2022 |
| 6 | 4 | Nick | 1 | 12-23-2021 |

As you can see in DimUser, user_code identifies a user uniquely, not user_id, but relatioinship is made to Fact table using user_id column. What I want to figure out is how to count the number of users by client in Fact table using the user_id column to access user_code values in DimUser table. I could create a calculated column in fact table retrieving the user_code related to the user_id and create a measure by simply using `DISTINCTCOUNT` function, but as I mentioned earlier, I want to avoid creation of calculated columns, this should be done using solely measures.

In the end I should visualize a chart table with the following information:

| client id | client name | Number of users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ecosapiens | 2 |
| 2 | Jalisco | 1 |
| 3 | Greenplant | 1 |

Because user_id values 1,2 and 3 are the same user (user_code = 1) and user_id values 4 and 5 are another user (user_code = 2), client_id 1 has 2 users, client_id 2 has just one user and client_id 3 has 1 user too.

How is the DAX code to create that measure?

I'd really appretiate if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following measure.

```
Number of Users = CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT('dimension'[user_code]), CROSSFILTER('fact'[user_id],'dimension'[user_id], Both))
```

[image]

[image]